# What type of variable Properties.Settings.Default c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a path to an setting "Properties.Settings.Default.Password1" and "Properties.Settings.Default.Password2".

Now I want to use one of these paths. I use the following code:

```
If (certain condition)
{
kindOfVariable passwordPath = Properties.Settings.Default.Password1
}
else
{
kindOfVariable passwordPath = Properties.Settings.Default.Password2
}
```

Well, I know that the password is a string, thats no problem but I want the path.

But what kind of variable do I have to use? Or is there another way to do this?

Normally you would save a new value like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.passwordPath = "New Password";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

What I wanna do with the path is to give a new value on that path, so for example

```
passwordPath = "New Password";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Can you please explain us more about the "path" you mean? though you have edited your question, it doesnt make much sense !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# 3.0 or later, `var` is a good choice.

That causes the compiler to [automatically infer the type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) of a local variable from the expression on the right side of its initialization statement.

```
if (certain condition)
{
   var Passwordpath = Properties.Settings.Default.Password1
}
else
{
   var Passwordpath = Properties.Settings.Default.Password2
}
```

Otherwise, hover over the right side of the initialization statement (`Password1`, for example) in the development environment. You should see a tooltip that gives away its type. Use that one.

(Off-topic suggestion: Name your local variables using camelCasing, as recommended by Microsoft's C# and .NET code style guidelines. The `Passwordpath` variable should really be `passwordPath`.)

---

**Edit** to answer updated question:

The simplest way is just to *reverse the logic*. Rather than trying to store the address of the property and set it to a new value later, just store the new value in a temporary variable, and use it to set the property directly. Maybe it would be easier to explain with some code...

```
// Get the new password
string password = "New Password";

// Set the appropriate property
if (certain condition)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Password1 = password;
}
else
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Password2 = password;
}

// Save the new password
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Well the password is off course an string so I can use a string. But I dont want the string in `Password1` but I want the path to it.

Comment: @Lars - I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say that you want the "path" to it. What path? The property shown simply contains a value. Storing that value in a local variable is the same thing as accessing it directly.

Comment: please have a look at my edit in my question, maybe you understand then.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use var - that makes the compiler decide the actual type for you (at compile time, so IntelliSense etc. can still take advantage of static typing).

```
var Passwordpath = Properties.Settings.Default.Password1
```

I'm not really sure what are you trying to do though.